# Section headings in the mobile app "Feed" display are unclear

Tags: discussion, ios-app, ios-app-feed

The iOS app shows the following sections:

```
JUST NOW
EARLIER TODAY
YESTERDAY
EARLIER THIS WEEK
EARLIER THIS MONTH
```

It's unclear what any of these section titles actually mean, and therefore they're not very useful. Is "EARLIER TODAY" an hour ago? Four hours? 12 hours? When does "YESTERDAY" start? My local time zone? UTC? Pacific time? When does the week start? Sunday? Monday? Whose time zone? Why am I seeing things from January in "EARLIER THIS MONTH"? It's February!

What would be more useful would be a section that shows new feed items. So the sections could be:

```
NEW
ALREADY VIEWED
```

along with *specific* date headings in the local time zone (10 FEB, 9 FEB, etc). The "ALREADY VIEWED" heading would be updated to indicate things I've already seen in a previous launch of the app (switching away from the app and back would be a reasonable action to update the ALREADY VIEWED marker).

Comment: Earlier today probably means since the last GMT rollover.  Yesterday means the 24 hour prior to that.  Everything else follows.

Comment: "probably"? How do I know? If that is so, UTC is particularly inconvenient for my local time zone, because the rollover happens around lunchtime.

Comment: Everything else having to do with days on Stack Exchange is based on GMT rollover.  In my time zone (PST) the rollover occurs at 4PM when we're not in Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: That certainly doesn't have to be true, however. The iOS app running on my phone knows what my local time zone is (this is a lot easier to deal with than the same problem in a web app). The way most people think about "days" is in their local time zone.

Comment: They'd have to change the way the entire network works with time to make it work that way on your phone.

Comment: That's certainly not true.

Comment: Well there you have it.

Comment: Sorry, what do I have? All I'm asking for is the app to use local time zone conventions when dealing with times displayed in the app. This doesn't have anything to do with "the way the entire network works with time".

Comment: Except that everything will work differently on your phone than it will on the desktop.  My desktop computer knows what time it is too, but the SE rollover still occurs at 4PM, even if I pretend that it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not talking about "rollover" (I presume you mean things like resetting close vote counts). All I'm suggesting is *local time display*.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that the entire Stack Exchange network assumes that the beginning of the day is zero hundred hours zulu.  That permeates through anything and everything that is time-sensitive, including the time descriptions you have in the OP.  You can adjust those displays to conform to local time; they'll just be *wrong,* that's all.

Comment: This whole discussion is moot, because the position of the "EARLIER TODAY" marker doesn't seem to have anything to do with the UTC rollover. It's moved, and not to the present time even though the UTC rollover just happened. It's showing at some point X hours in the past, and it's unclear what X is. That's the question I described in my question.

Comment: Then it is a bug.  EARLIER TODAY is supposed to be the hours after midnight UTC.

Comment: The app, probably incorrectly, considers anything < 24 hours ago to be "earlier today."  The other phrases similarly are generated without concern for calendar boundaries.  I changed the tag to make this a bug.

Comment: Could you post the second half of the OP as a separate [meta-tag:feature-request]?  It's helpful to us if we can deal with these things separately.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at this more closely, I'll say that the app is doing the right thing.  Just like the site, all times are with respect to UTC. The biggest source of confusion will be when your localized calendar boundaries seem to disagree with UTC boundaries, but that's really unavoidable without localizing everything to a timezone, and we're not going to do that because

- the site is all UTC
- it will just replace this confusion with other confusion

As for what those labels mean, I'm more than happy to share.  Here they are:

```
JUST NOW               < 1 hour
EARLIER TODAY          < 24 hours
YESTERDAY              < 48 hours
EARLIER THIS WEEK      < 168 hours
EARLIER THIS MONTH     < 720 hours (24 * 30)
EARLIER THIS YEAR      < 8760 hours (24 * 365)
A LONG TIME AGO        >= 8760 hours
```

Comment: "WITHIN THE LAST HOUR" (or similar) might be a little less ambiguous than "JUST NOW"; the rest of them seem intuitive enough to me.

Comment: Earlier this month has a very different meaning from '<720 hours'.  Mar 2, only Mar 1 should show up in 'earlier this month'.  'Within the last month' perhaps or 'less than a month ago' would be better.  (And doesn't the language you're writing this in have a proper function for 'a month ago' rather than the crude approximation of 720 hours?)

Comment: I would love for this table to get put into the help for the iOS app. Would that even make sense or is this documented elsewhere that can be indexed / provided to users of the app? Also, wouldn't "WITHIN A WEEK" be better than "EARLIER THIS WEEK" and substituting WITHIN A for EARLIER THIS in all cases above?

Answer (score 0):

I would support modifying the text as follows for relative time bins so that they don't imply so strongly a day/month/year hard boundary "THIS". By having EARLIER which means *near the beginning of the particular time period* and THIS MONTH referring to a *specific month* rather than a relative time span lasting a month.

```
RECENTLY               < 1 hour
LAST 24 HOURS          < 24 hours
YESTERDAY              < 48 hours
WITHIN A WEEK          < 168 hours
WITHIN A MONTH         < 720 hours (24 * 30)
WITHIN A YEAR          < 8760 hours (24 * 365)
MORE THAN A YEAR AGO   >= 8760 hours
```

The above terms more closely match what I would expect when looking at events that happened in the past relative to now as opposed to specific week/day/month boundaries.