# The iOS app feed lists a featured meta post that is no longer tagged featured

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, ios-app, ios-app-feed

My iOS feed has three items in "just now" before the "earlier today" section begins.

- A featured meta post at top
- One job recommendation
- Two new replies

The featured post is no longer tagged featured ([that tag was removed 20 hours ago](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/timeline/2087)) and items from that time frame are sorted well below the featured post. My guess is a featured post is given high weight and if so, this might be a good behavior that an odd window of removal of the featured tag exploited.

Could a developer look and see if this is the expected behavior based on the [definitions of relative time on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223275/165931)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's likely expected behavior.

1. We had a bug in the mobile feed which prevented it to return all the correct posts.
2. On the other hand, the items used to build the mobile feed come from a shared cache (per site, or in general, depending on type). Cache time is fairly long (1 day)
3. Finally, I fixed the bug this morning GMT.

My guess is that the feed started returning items which are still in cache, but later than expected due to a bug being solved.

Please let us know it this behavior repeats, in which case my guess is wrong and we'll need to dig further.

Comment: I haven't caught things off so badly for a while. If I do again, I'll document it here...

Comment: Actually, the 'featured meta post' entries in the app are just 'hot meta posts', and are disconnected from the 'featured' tag.